# Online-first object creation on a synchronized Realm, to guarantee client object ownership

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a need to pre-allocate concise integer primary keys (from a contiguous range) for my synchronized database clients.

The use case is pretty simple: I need to print tickets with short serial numbers on them, in a situation where the mobile clients have intermittent connectivity.  The numbers must be short enough to be read over a bad PA system in a noisy environment, to award door prizes.

Realm seems perfect for the task -- but I need to allow each client to pre-allocate itself a pool of guaranteed-unique serial numbers when they're connected to the server, so they can print tickets later, even when offline.

```
class TicketNumber extends RealmObject { 
    @PrimaryKey int serialNumber;
    String clientId; // instance identifier unique to each client
}
```

My intent is that Client A executes a transaction to create a bunch of `TicketNumber` objects starting at max(serialNumber)+1, setting its own clientId on each one.  I was hoping that I could rely on the transaction to fail (throwing ObjectExists) if client B had already created `TicketNumber` objects in that range.

However, if either client A or client B is disconnected at creation time, it will merrily create local copies in the same range.  When the sync happens, it sets the `clientId` of the conflicting object to whichever client "created" it last.  Obviously that's a problem for me if both clients have already printed a ticket with the same serial number.

As I see it, to guarantee client ownership of the ticket numbers, I'll need to do my object creation "online-first", so I can observe and react to conflicts.  Is there any way to know the connectivity status of a realm client?  Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  Do I have to wait for Counters to be available?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to generate local ID's across distributed devices is not to use an integer and restricted ranges, but UUID's: `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` should be good enough as it is a 128-bit value. The chance of faulty hardware messing up or earth rays swapping bits are bigger than two keys being the same on two devices.

This is basically what all other distributed databases does as well.

Comment: That suggests that for 100 tickets among 4 clients, I'd create a compound key with a UUID + a locally incremented number 0-24.  That increases the length of my key by a factor of 19, from 7 bits to 128+5.  It doesn't really address my need of pre-allocating sequential serial numbers.  Edited question to include that serial numbers must be concise and preferably from a numerically contiguous range.